# word problem with natural numbers?

Tags: arithmetic, word-problem

> Jenny writes the natural numbers from 1 to 1001 in a row.
>
> 1. Can the signs ”+” and ”-” be placed between the numbers in such a way that the value of the resulting expression is 100? If yes, show an example. If not, provide a mathematical reason why.
> 2. How about -499? If yes, show an example. If not, show the reason why.

I'm not entirely sure what the question means.
Is it expecting me to be able to write down every number from 1 to 1001 and then do this by trial and error.
There has to be a better way to do it right?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: The point of the number $1000$ is that it is too large to try all the cases, so requires that you understand what is going on.  Making the targets large makes it unreasonable to try small cases.  An important thing to note is that when you change the sign in front of a number $k$ the sum changes by $2k$, so whether numbers are even or odd will be important.

Comment: Please use a more specific title.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1)When you $1\pm 2$ you get an odd number, now what number odd or even do you get when you add or subtract $3$, then $4$ and so on. Can you establish a pattern?

2) So the sum is $-499$
We know that the numbers can be partitioned into $500$ pairs and $1$ lone number.
 Do you notice that $-500+1=499$

Can you find that lone number, and also the relationship between the numbers which are in the same pair?